# VS xml documentation, inheriting from base class

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, documentation

I have enabled generating XML documentation on my class library which has one parent class and many inherited classes from it. There are several properties overridden from base class properties. I would like to put XML comments on base class properties and get the same comments on overridden properties. Unfortunately when I generate XML Doc file the comments are missing on overridden properties. Is it possible to override xml comments from base class?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tools you use to generate the external documentation (Doxygen, Sandcastle, etc) you may be able to use an `include` or similar element to pull in documentation from elsewhere so it can be shared.

Another approach is to use `see`, `seealso` or `sa` entries (again, depending on the tool you process the documentation comments with) to reference the base class property/method, but this will mean a hyperlink to the base entry, not inlined documentation.

A third possibiility is my addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/). (Among other things) it will duplicate the documentation from the base class/interface up into your override/implementation, so it only takes a moment to copy the documentation. You can then modify the copied documentation to be more specific to the particular method it is attached to.

Comment: I use native VS 2010 XML document generator and as I know it do not support tags which you have listed above.